# IBM Lotus Notes embedded Excel object. Data read via OLE does not match data in Workbook. Until workbook is manually opened and saved

Tags: excel, office365, lotus-notes, ole, office-2016

We've got a Domino/Notes application with a few thousand Notes Docs which contain an embedded Excel workbook. The data has to date been copied from the Workbook using Field Exchange. This has proven to be unreliable and I'm currently writing an Agent to do the data copy via OLE instead. (yes, it can fail due to the same reasons that Field Exchange does, but at least this way it's obvious and can flag/prompt to retry)

The problem is SOME of the data, specifically Dates, read via OLE does not match the data in the embedded Workbook. However if the workbook is manually opened and saved it can then be read correctly.
When I open the workbook manually I can see the expected data. However if I don't save the Notes Doc, the Agent can never read the correct data.

Currently using Office 2016, the original macro enable Embedded Excel object was created using Excel 2007 I.e.  Class  = Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12

The cells are read via Excel's Value2 function

```
Dim Value As Variant
Value = handle.Application.Range("example").Value2
```

The value returned from the cell is then converted according to it expected datatype. 
When examined using the debugger it can be seen that some date values are incorrect even before any date conversion is performed.

I'm not sure that this is a Domino/Notes Problem or an Excel ver 12 to ver 16  problem. But at the moment either seems possible.

Comment: Have you really written this as an Agent, not as event code contained in an action button on the Notes form?

Comment: Hi Richard. Yes it's an Agent. It reads all docs containing the embedded workbook. It's purpose is to check if the previously saved Docs fields have been updated correctly from the workbook.

Comment: Hi Richard. Yes it's an Agent. It reads all docs containing the embedded workbook. It's purpose is to check if the previously saved Docs fields have been updated correctly from the workbook. The Forms currently still use Field exchange but that will be replaced by OLE code once the Agent can be demonstrated to function correctly.

Comment: OLE is inherently a front-end technology. How are you running this agent? I'm pretty doggone sure that it's going to have to be in the client, not the server. Can you post the code?

Comment: Yes, the agent is run on a client with Excel 2016 installed, ATM. The Agent only uses Notes.Document classes. I.e. not UI Classes so it might run on a server with Excel installed, but that is not something I've tried or need to do at this point. Thought it would be easier to get the Agent working correctly on a client first and explore running it on the server it was to be run more frequently., Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have problems running it on a server, even with Excel installed, unless Domino is running as a regular user process instead of as a service. Otherwise, there are security restrictions on services that are likely to get in the way of launching Excel and using OLE.